# Center div when it takes 12 column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an element in Bootstrap row. The element takes different amount of columns on xs, sm, md and lg configurations of a screen. I need the element to be in the middle when it takes 12 columns. Is it possible? If so how can I do that?
For example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    SOME TEXT
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    SOME TEXT
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    SOME TEXT
</div>
```

And if I put the row into a div which is fluid I want elements always be in the middle, but when I shrink browser to sm configuration it makes an element take 12 columns by itself and hence I have relatively to the gap on left side huge gap on right.

Comment: DId you use **text-center** class?

Comment: Yep. And it didn`t work for me.

Comment: @GaneshRadhakrishnan, oh. I misunderstood. I read text-align: center. What is it text-center class could you explain, please?

Comment: i think its same as the style **text-align: center**

Comment: I don't understand "I have relatively to the gap on left side huge gap on right"... Can you make a fiddle or bootply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! There I came out with the idea and it seems to work out. I just add a bit of css to a elements which take columns:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

and what the code does is actually centers the elements in their columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @GaneshRadhakrishnan is right, you should use bootstrap's [center-text](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) class like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 center-text">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 center-text">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 center-text">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it work only for text or for all elements in row?